# getApplication use in onClick method

Tags: android

I use Application to access my data.
And while buttom be click, I want to use the data which in Application.
I use below code:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
MyData md = (MyData)this.getApplication();
md.setName("");
md.setIP("");
}
});
```

But the error show:

```
The method getApplication() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

How to use getApplication in onClick method?

Comment: In onclicklistener you get view as v, so try like this..v.getApplicationContext();

Comment: are you using Application class for having global access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By getApplication(), I assume you are referring to [Activity.getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29).
In this case, if you remove the `this` it should work.

```
MyData md = (MyData)getApplication();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this,

To set the Name -

```
 ((MyApplication)getApplication()).setName("StackOverflow");
```

To get the Name -

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your class is called `Example`.
In the `onCreate` you could do:
`Example.this.getApplication();`

Or, an alternate, more complex method, which I actually prefer is:
In your class body declare `Activity activity;`, then in your `onCreate` declare `activity = this;`, then in your `onClick` declare `activity.getApplication();` like so:

```
public class Example extends Activity{

        Activity activity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(...);

        activity = this;

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  activity.getApplication();

            }
        };

}
```

**EDIT:**
Or remove `this`. That should work, also.

Answer (score 1):

The "this" in java means the class you are in.

So the class you are in onClick(View v) is "b".
"b" doesn't have getApplication() method, which is correct.

You may refer to something when you use this.

do something like

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    public initB(){
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setMyData();
           }
        });
    }


    public setMyData(){
        MyData md = (MyData)this.getApplication();
        md.setName("");
        md.setIP("");
    }
}
```

So now, when you use this, this refers to MyActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created an activity like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

....

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
MyData md = (MyData)MainActivity.this.getApplication();
md.setName("");
md.setIP("");
}
});

....

}
```

Use your class name and then this.getApplication() because "this" you used will point to the View.onClickLIstener Method.... since It doesn't have any getApplication method It is throwing this error. :)